# SQL Server "String or binary data would be truncated" XML Insert

Tags: sql-server, xml

I am relatively new to SQL Server. Most of my background is MS Access. I have a stored procedure that takes an XML file and inserts the node information into 16 different tables. I am getting a "String or binary data would be truncated" error. Here is the piece of the code that is causing the issue:

```
DECLARE @xml XML
DECLARE @filename varchar(255);

Select @filename = 'SilvxInSightImport_uslsss17_14-08-24_20-40-00.xml'
--Select @filename = @filepath

Select @xml = 
CONVERT(XML,bulkcolumn,2) FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'C:\Users\Kevin.Smith\Documents\TDAT\CPOFiles\SilvxInSightImport_uslsss17_14-08-31_20-40-01.xml',SINGLE_BLOB) AS X


Insert into [SILVX_CIRCUIT]
(
FileName, md_group,pkey,s_state,circuit_name,admin,protection,vpnid,sourcereroute,trunkrestoration,fwdbw,
sourcetype,sourceip,sourcechassis,sourceslot,sourceport,sourcechannel,destinationtype,
destinationip,destinationchassis,destinationslot,destinationport,destinationchannel,circuitpath,
reversion,cg_net_instance,parent_hpkey
)

select @filename,
       T.X.value('(MD_GROUP/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(255)') as MD_GROUP,
       T.X.value('(PKEY/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(255)') as PKEY,
       T.X.value('(S_STATE/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(255)') as S_STATE,
       T.X.value('(CIRCUIT_NAME/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(255)') as CIRCUIT_NAME,
       T.X.value('(ADMIN/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(255)') as ADMIN,
       T.X.value('(PROTECTION/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(255)') as PROTECTION,
       T.X.value('(SOURCEREROUTE/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(255)') as SOURCEREROUTE,
       T.X.value('(TRUNKRESTORATION/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(255)') as TRUNKRESTORATION,
       T.X.value('(FWDBW/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(255)') as FWDBW,
       T.X.value('(SOURCETYPE/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(255)') as SOURCETYPE,
       T.X.value('(SOURCEIP/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(255)') as SOURCEIP,
       T.X.value('(SOURCECHASSIS/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(255)') as SOURCECHASSIS,
       T.X.value('(SOURCESLOT/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(255)') as SOURCESLOT,
       T.X.value('(SOURCEPORT/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(255)') as SOURCEPORT,
       T.X.value('(SOURCECHANNEL/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(255)') as SOURCECHANNEL,
       T.X.value('(DESTINATIONTYPE/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(255)') as DESTINATIONTYPE,
       T.X.value('(DESTINATIONIP/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(255)') as DESTINATIONIP,
       T.X.value('(DESTINATIONCHASSIS/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(255)') as DESTINATIONCHASSIS,
       T.X.value('(DESTINATIONSLOT/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(255)') as DESTINATIONSLOT,
       T.X.value('(DESTINATIONPORT/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(255)') as DESTINATIONPORT,
       T.X.value('(DESTINATIONCHANNEL/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(255)') as DESTINATIONCHANNEL,
       **T.X.value('(CIRCUITPATH/text())[1]', 'varchar(8000)')  as CIRCUITPATH,
       T.X.value('(CIRCUITPROTECTPATH/text())[1]', 'varchar(8000)') as CIRCUITPROTECTPATH,**
       T.X.value('(REVERSION/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(255)') as REVERSION,
       T.X.value('(CG_NET_INSTANCE/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(255)') as CG_NET_INSTANCE,
       T.X.value('(PARENT_HPKEY/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(255)') as PARENT_HPKEY

from @XML.nodes('/SilvxInSightImport/Tables/Table[@Name = "Circuit"]/TableData/Row') as T(X)
```

The bolded code is the issue. I have checked the destination table (SILVX_CIRCUIT) and changed the datatypes for CIRCUITPATH and CIRCUITPROTECTPATCH fields to VARCHAR(8000) but I still get the error. If I set the above from varchar(8000) to varchar(255) it runs without error, but truncates the data to a length of 255 as you might expect. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Thank you in advance for helping a noob!

Comment: Not sure if there's a programmatic side to this as well, if so you might consider taking said data and compressing it first, and then passing it through as binary data?  Don't know if this is viable or not in your case though...

Comment: There is sth wrong with the query you have posted: 22nd argument: destinationport -> DESTINATIONCHANNEL (?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you examine carefully how the columns in the `INSERT` statement match with the columns being selected by the `SELECT` statement then you will realize that `CIRCUITPATH` is being inserted in place of `destinationchannel` column.

`destinationchannel` is `NVARCHAR(255)`, whereas `CIRCUITPATH` is `VARCHAR(8000)`, so you get an error.

Comment: @Kevin_S You' re welcome. You can accept this post as an answer to your question, if it really helped you solve your ploblem, so that other people having a similar problem might benefit from this post.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could change this:

```
varchar(8000)
```

to this:

```
varchar(max)
```

Comment: I tried that first with the same result. Also, most of the the data in the CIRCUITPATH AND CIRCUITPROTECTPATH fields are between 100 and 600 characters in length.